# Google still indexes pages months after redirecting

Tags: seo

We have an event search engine on our site. When an event is over, we keep it viewable for 3 months along with a message telling people that this event is over. After these 3 month, we simply redirect with a 301 to the homepage for the search engine.

The problem is that we have yearly events, and google won't "forget" about those events, even after 5/6 months of redirecting with a 301 to another page. So each year, if you google our site about one of these events, you have two links:

1. last year's event that will redirect you on our events search engine
2. one that will take you to the thing you probably searched for

I thought of doing things differently, always showing events, even after 3 months, and instead of redirecting, simply add a noindex meta, would it be better ? should I do anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

If the event is an annual event and you only keep event webpages online for three months after the event, I would suggest reusing the same URL for the event each year.